# C# MVC Controller is incorrectly parsing JSON From a POST

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reflection

I am trying to make the dropdown lists on my site modifiable by the admins on the site. The options on the dropdowns are stored alongside associated data as an IDropDownEntity, e.g. JobPriority has string Name and string PriorityColor, Branch has string Name and AddressValueObject Address, and so on. The form on the View works properly, but when I POST it to the controller as JSON, the associated data values are not parsing / are parsing as null.

I take the IDropDownEntity and use reflection and custom attributes to determine which properties are meant to be user-editable, and put the result in a DropDownEditViewModel like:

```
public class DropDownEditViewModel
{
    //constructor()
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<DDLEntityEditableProperty> EditableProperties { get; set; } = new();
}

public class DDLEntityEditableProperty
{
    //constructor()
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object? Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have inputs for the Name and the EditableProperties, and JQuery that sends JSON to a controller action which takes a DropDownEditViewModel, but on the controller action the value is always coming up null.

```
//javascript that generates JSON like so in a "var formData":
"Id": "1",
  "Name": "Home Office",
  "ExtraFields": [
    {
      "Name": "PhoneNumber",
      "Value": "111-555-0000",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Address",
      "Value": {
        "Address1": "404 Parse Street",
        "Locality": "Notfound",
        "PostCode": "00404"
      }
    }
  ]
}

//posts to controller using jQuery:
$.post("/DropDowns/EditGenericDropDownEntity", formData, function (result, status) {
    ShowNotification(result.success, result.message);
});
```

sent to a controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditGenericDropDownEntity(DropDownEditViewModel model)
{
    //model's "Value" is always null
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Json(new {success = false, text = ModelState.GetError()});
    else return Ok();
}
```

I have tried changing the List to a Dictionary<string, object?> but got identical issue (key came across fine, value was null). I have also tried sending the json to the controller as a string to parse using Newtonsoft but could not get that to work either. Are there any other steps I could take, or is reflection not an option for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using form-data content type (by default) , but it can not contain any nested objects, it should be a dictionary<string,string> like. Try to use a json content type, you need the full form of a jquery request for this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "...your url",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData)
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (result) {
       
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And  add [FromBody] to the action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditGenericDropDownEntity([FromBody] DropDownEditViewModel model)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Serge; after adding `[FromBody]` the POST instead fails with a 415 error code (Unsupported Media Type). I have edited my question to include the line of JS that sends the POST (just the jQuery `$.post()` method) for clarity.

Comment: After following the updated solution using $.ajax() instead of $.post(), my issue is resolved. Thank you for the help!